# loading image fro MYSQL into Imageview

Tags: ios, objective-c, image, post, loading

I have tried to find this answer for days now and cant find anything. I store url to image in my database and Im trying to get this url and load the image to a ImageView.

Users uploads a image and my PHP script makes a url to the image in the database. This is my database table: ID -> Username -> Password ->  urlImage. And I have another PHP script that takes the username and askes for the urlImage.

In Xcode i want to add this: ` 
    NSUserDefaults *settings = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSString *user = [settings valueForKey:@"username"];

```
NSString *post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"username=%@&image=dummy",user];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] autorelease];

[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://url.com/Wish_Profile_Pic.php"]];
NSString *postLen = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%d" ,[post length ]];
[request setValue:postLen forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"content-type"];
//this is hard coded based on your suggested values, obviously you'd probably need to make this more dynamic based on your application's specific data to send

[request setHTTPBody:[post dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
```

`

This will send a request to the database sever and the server will output the urlImage. How can I view the image in the ImageView? Cant find anything about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
NSString *post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"username=%@&image=dummy",use];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://url.com/Wish_Profile_Pic.php"]];
NSString *postLen = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%d" ,[post length ]];
[request setValue:postLen forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"content-type"];
[request setHTTPBody:[post dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *r, NSData *data, NSError *e) {
    if(data.length) {
        UIImage *img = [[[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data] autorelease];

        //try base64 
        if(!img) {
            //NEEDS http://projectswithlove.com/projects/NSData_Base64.zip
           id b64 = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] autorelease];
           id data2 = [NSData dataFromBase64String:b64];
           img = [[[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data2] autorelease];
        }
        if(img)
            self.imageView.image = img;
    }
    else if(e)
        NSLog(@"%@", e);
}];
```

Comment: I will try this right away, but looks like something I need :)

Comment: this does the post async and when it comes back you get the image from the response data

Comment: I tried this in the ViewDidLoad and had to change this line to self->imageView.image = img; but didnt see anything in my imageview. Do you have a tutorial or something on this? Or how did you go with this? It should be just just simple o make a IBOutlet UIImageView * imageView in .h and your code in .m right?

Comment: yes. if you have an imageView just set its image. make sure the url is ok and the data you get back is ok and the image isnt nil when you set it. put a breakpoint onto the line ... .image = img

Comment: also check if the data you get back is base64 encoded, it might be :) then you need to decode it ... i will update the example with that

Comment: (typed inline . and ultimately you should no what the server returns and.... base64 IS likely .. my bad)

Comment: Yeah, when im not enctypting anything in my PHP script. When I test my script on my computer in Safari it just echo´s out URL: like http://url.com/images/3424252.png But if I encrypt my output now in my PHP file and use your new script it will work? ;)